# HD Detected as null When Installing El Capitan

Tags: macos, install

I created a bootable image on a USB drive using this method:

https://www.macissues.com/2015/10/01/how-to-overcome-os-x-10-11-el-capitan-not-installing/

Basically, formatting a USB drive, calling it INSTALLER, and using a previously downloaded installer to create the bootable image on the thumb drive with this command:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/INSTALLER --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app --nointeraction
```

This seems to work, and the install process does indeed kick off after reboot, but now the problem is that when I get to the screen where I am asked to select which drive to install OS X on, I am given two choices:  The INSTALLER drive (a USB drive I am booting from) and "(null)".  The icon above (null) is that of a standard hard drive, so I select it and am given the error message that there is not enough space on (null) to install OSX.

So, first, that is not the name of the drive. And second, according to my disk utility I have over 140 gigs free on the drive so I know this is just a false error on the part of the installer.

So how to resolve? I have tried installing several times and I get the same result each time so I know it is not a one-off problem.  Why is the hard drive detecting as (null)?

The 251 gig volume is a single volume with Mac OS Extended (Journaled) format:
[image]

Comment: 140 gigs free may mean several things: 1. 140 GB of unallocated disk space 2. 140 GB of free space in an arbitrary volume. If 2: what's the file system and if HFS+ 2a: does it already contain a system and if yes El Cap or newer?

Comment: Thank you for your questions. I am updating the post description with a pic, but I will also answer them here: the 251 gig drive is a single volume, the file system is Mac OS Extended (Journaled), and it already contains an os in the form of Yosemite,